# Mongo aggregate query Boolean condition always returns true

Tags: mongodb, boolean, aggregation-framework

```
[{    "_id" : ObjectId("610d10db038380dde8f33bcc"),
    "__type" : "TaskPlannedBOQ",
    "boqType" : "4",
 },
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("610d10db038380dde8f33bc9"),
    "__type" : "TaskPlannedResource",
}]
```

```
 let result = (await sampleModel.aggregate([
{ $project: {  boqType: { $ifNull:["$boqType", "0"]},__type: { $ifNull:["$__type", "0"]}}},
{ $project: { status: {$cond: [{$or: [{ __type: "TaskPlannedResource" },{ boqType: "1" }]},true,false]}}}]))
```

`status` column always results to true, WHY?

only one row should show `status` column true for
`{ __type: "TaskPlannedResource" }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to correct the syntax of equal to `$eq` in condition `$cond` operation, you have used query condition but this requires expression `$eq` condition operator,

```
  {
    $project: {
      status: {
        $cond: [
          {
            $or: [
              { $eq: ["$__type", "TaskPlannedResource"] },
              { $eq: ["$boqType", "1"] }
            ]
          },
          true,
          false
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/O675zQWnhnm)

---

The second option as well, the `$or` or any expression operator condition will return true/false, so no need to use `$cond` operator,

```
  {
    $project: {
      status: {
        $or: [
          { $eq: ["$__type", "TaskPlannedResource"] },
          { $eq: ["$boqType", "1"] }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_slfHa_BL5f)

---

The third option is to merge both `$project` stages in single, you can put `$ifNull` condition inside `$eq` instead of direct field name,

```
let result = (await sampleModel.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      status: {
        $or: [
          {
            $eq: [
              { $ifNull: ["$__type", "0"] },
              "TaskPlannedResource"
            ]
          },
          {
            $eq: [
              { $ifNull: ["$boqType", "0"] },
              "1"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]));
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Mxlkl0122-W)